# Jmeter - bzm Streaming Sampler Content Protection

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

We use Jmeter with the BZM - Streaming Sampler to load test a streaming service. With this we are requesting a dash main.mpd file. That url would look like:
https://url.com/5bf9c52c17e072d89e6527d45587d03826512bfa3b53a30bb90ecd7ed1bb7a77/dash/Main.mpd

Within the schema we have defined ContentProtection with value="cenc" as such:

```xml
<ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" cenc:default_KID="string" value="cenc"></ContentProtection>
```

This schema is being auto-generated via a third party code source... So, we do not have much flexibility to change the order... I mention this because with the below schema (from a previous version of the xml generator) Jmeter works perfectly fine:

```xml
<ContentProtection value="cenc" schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" cenc:default_KID="string"/>
```

The issue we are now facing is that jmeter is throwing this error:

```java
2022-03-14 07:15:40,574 WARN c.b.j.v.c.VideoStreamingSampler: Problem downloading playlist
com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.exception.PlaylistParsingException: Error parsing contents from https://url/5bf9c52c17e072d89e6527d45587d03826512bfa3b53a30bb90ecd7ed1bb7a77/dash/Main.mpd
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.dash.Manifest.fromUriAndBody(Manifest.java:56) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.3.jar:?]
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.VideoStreamingSampler.downloadPlaylist(VideoStreamingSampler.java:20) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.3.jar:?]
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.dash.DashSampler.sample(DashSampler.java:34) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.3.jar:?]
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.videostreaming.core.VideoStreamingSampler.sample(VideoStreamingSampler.java:79) [jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.3.jar:?]
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.hls.logic.HlsSampler.sample(HlsSampler.java:198) [jmeter-bzm-hls-3.0.3.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "cenc" (for attribute "default_KID")
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [5,141]
```

My question is, can I alter this payload before it is ingested by Streaming Sampler to change the ContentProtection string? Or, can I automatically set the ContentProtection value as "cenc"?

#### EDIT

After digging through my main.mpd XML I found that the "cenc" namespace was left out. After adding:

```xml
xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013"
```

To the file, the main.mpd worked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to:

1. Download the playlist using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener so it would be saved to your local drive. See [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for more comprehensive instructions if needed
2. Amend the playlist as needed using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)
3. In the **bzm - Streaming Sampler** use local URL via [`file` URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) i.e.

   ```
   file:///folder/anotherFolder/playlist.mpd
   ```

You can also [raise an issue in the plugin repo](https://github.com/Blazemeter/HLSPlugin/issues) or if you're a BlazeMeter Customer [open a BlazeMeter support ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

Comment: Let me see if I can get this to work. It seems exactly like what I need. Also, I have opened a bug with BlazeMeter HLS plugin:
https://github.com/Blazemeter/HLSPlugin/issues/27

Comment: This solution will work, however I found the root of the issue. The namespace for "cenc" was left out, thus throwing an error. I can alter the xml to add the namespace using Jmeter, but will obviously work to fix the actual issue.